# How to turn Add Fields on in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, raster-attribute-table

I am trying to add a new field to the Attributed Table of a raster layer (in TIFF format) in ArcGIS Pro, but the "Add" option in the Attribute Table is greyed out. To clarify, I am not in editing mode. Also, the "Add" option is already active on my shapefiles, and is only off for my raster layers.

PS: In ArcMap it perfectly works! So, I am sure there is nothing wrong with the Raster.

Comment: Your raster needs to be integer not float.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware of this condition, and it is integer. In fact, I can add fields to its Attribute Table in ArcMap, but not in ArcGIS Pro. So, I do not think this is the conditions of the raster.

Comment: Did you try the Add Field tool in the Data Management group?

Comment: Thank you! It worked!